# Angular Dynamic Formarray multiple dropdown selecting first dropdown affect another

Tags: angular, dynamic, dropdown, refresh, formarray

trying to load two dropdowns,first dropdown load on page init and need to load the second dropdown on changing the first dropdown.the dropdown can be viewed as select category and corresponding item
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4NOP.png)

I created 5 rows and changing the first dropdown affect all the second dropdowns,i only want to change the corresponding item and category without affecting other rows

i have attached the current working stack blitz link:

[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-dynamic-form-array-w3dqua?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as code blocks in your question, a Stackblitz is a great addition, but this question becomes useless if/when the link dies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.